# Criar coluna condicional considerando valor do mês anterior

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Tenho um dataframe com venda de cada cliente, basicamente preciso classificar o cliente no mês como churn (perda) ou não.

Para isso a condição é que, se o cliente no mês de referência (atual) está inativo E no mês passado estava ativo, retornar "churn" pois é um cliente perdido, caso contrário, retornar na.

Consegui fazer isso, mas o problema é que não consigo criar uma estrutura para se o valor no mês anterior for nulo, ir para o próximo mês anterior.

Por exemplo, o Paulo estava on em 02/2021, e em 10/2021 estava off, então deveria retornar "churn" e não "na".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'month_year':['jan/21', 'feb/21', 'mar/21', 'nov/21', 'oct/21', 'apr/21', 'apr/21', 'jan/21', 'jan/21'], 
                 'name':['joao', 'paulo', 'joao', 'joao', 'paulo', 'joao', 'joao', 'paulo', 'paulo'], 
                 'sale_value':[10000, 15000, 3000, 6000, 3000, 1500, 9000, 2000, 4000], 
                  'status':['on', 'on', 'off',  'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'off']})

list_datetime = [datetime.strptime(x, '%b/%y') for x in list(df['month_year'])]

df['month_year'] = list_datetime

df = df.groupby(['month_year', 'name']).agg({'sale_value':'sum','status':'last'})

for df['name'] in list_datetime:
    cond_churn = [
    ((df['status'] == 'on') & (df['status'].shift(periods=-1) == 'off')
    | ((df['status'] == 'off') & (df['status'].shift(periods=-1) == 'off'))
    | ((df['status'] == 'on') & (df['status'].shift(periods=-1) == 'on')))]
    return_churn = ['na']
    df['churn'] = np.select(cond_churn, return_churn, default='churn')

df.head(10)
```

Comment: Pelo que você descreveu, basta converter a coluna `month_year` para o formato `datetime` e depois ordenar o dataframe por `name, month_year`. Feito isso, o que for `off` é `churn`

Comment: Não dá certo, se for off no mês atual e no mês anterior também for off, não é churn.

Comment: Tem certeza que `cond_churn` está correta? Sugiro, ao invés de usar `|` (or) usar `,`. Com isso vc pode ver onde está o erro. Seria mais ou menos assim: `cond_churn = [ cond1, cond2, cond3 ]` e o `return_churn = [ 'na', 'nb', 'nc']`. Ou seja, se a condição `cond1` for `True`, será retornado `na`, se a `cond2` for `True`, será retornado `nb`...